# Google Calendar API error : "Bad request" when using "French special characters" like é, è or ç

Tags: google-calendar-api

When I put characters like é, è or ç in the description of my request I get this error :

```json
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

When I do a request like that I have no error :

```json
{
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2023-08-23T15:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2023-08-23T16:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "summary": "RDV",
        "description": "description without special character",
        "location": "Address",
        "colorId": "7"
}
```

But if I add a "é" or another special character in the request body I get the error written upper :

```json
{
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2023-08-23T15:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2023-08-23T16:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "summary": "RDV",
        "description": "description with a é or a ç",
        "location": "Address",
        "colorId": "7"
}
```

So is there a way to solve this issue or is a there a list of the "frobidden" characters ?

Comment: Try encoding non-ASCII characters as HTML entities, e.g. instead of `é` use `&#233;`.